# IPv6 validity test failed. What does this mean?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, ipv6

When I use https://ipv6-test.com/validate.php to test my website for IPv6 ready, (example on a domain www.[private].com), the test is failed and it returns error:

```
IPv6 web server     web server is unreachable : Connection refused
```

The other test sites like https://ready.chair6.net/ also failed the test with various errors about ipv6.

I have checked there is no error on the server when doing the test and I have done various things to enable ipv6. finally, I decided to ignore this problem as I don't know why the test failed but I can still ping the ipv6 address on my server. but I only have  this question in mind:

does the test conclude that the website www.[private].com only accessible from a client who only connect using ipv6 address? If yes then I should be concern. What do you think?

Edit for clarification (to answer @Piotr P. Karwasz):

1) the server does listening to the IPv6:

[image]

2) This is the output of the ip6tables -nVL INPUT (note that I also disabled the firewall completely to test the site but connection refuse still there when doing curl like you have mentioned)

[image]

3) About the listening directive. Yes, the ipv6 listening directive is there. example the server got this setting:

```
server {

 listen ipv4:80
 listen ipv6:80 ipv6only=on;

}

server {
 listen ipv4:443 ssl http2
 listen ipv6:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on;
}
```

4) The Ipv6 configuration is enabled:

[image]

also when doing this command:

```
[ -f /proc/net/if_inet6 ] && echo 'IPv6 ready system!' || echo 'No IPv6 support found! Compile the kernel!!'
```

The output is:

```
IPv6 ready system!
```

5) When doing this: netstat -napl | grep 80
Seems like nginx and httpd are running on ipv6 with no issue. 
The output is:

[image]

Other things about this server:

a) nginx_apache as reverse proxy (nginx as frontend and apache as backend)

b) Operating system is Centos 8

c) Using directadmin host at linode (linode has verified that there is no problem with IPv6 at their side).

Edit: Solved. Thanks to @Piotr P. Karwasz for pointing out that there was a typo in IP. It was a typo for one character IP where I put f305 instead of fe05

Edited domain name to prevent indexing by Search Engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tested if your host is reachable via IPv6 with `ping`, but you didn't actually connect to it on port 80:

```
curl -6 -i http://www.example.com/
```

The connection fails. This means that either:

- your server does not listen on an IPv6 socket. You can check this with:

  ```
  netstat -6nl | grep 80
  ```

  looking for a line like:

  ```
  tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
  ```

and than check the `Listen` directives in your configuration.

- a firewall is blocking the IPv6 port. Check with:

  ```
  ip6tables -nvL INPUT
  ```

  and if the policy is `DROP` and you don't have an `ACCEPT` rule for port 80, you need to add it.

**Edit**: After your clarifications it seems you made a typo entering you IPv6 address in **nginx** configuration: you forgot the last 8 hex digits of the address. Unless you really need to specify on which address should **nginx** listen, just specify all addresses:

```
listen *:80;
listen [::]:80;
```

Comment: Hai, thanks a lot for your reply, I have updated my question to answer your post.

Comment: I edited the answer based on the information you provided: you have the wrong IPv6 bind address in your `listen` directive.

Comment: Sorry i thought u were talking about the output. let me check

Comment: Hai, thanks a lot. it's indeed typo in the IP address. This issue is solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hai, is it possible that the domain name you have written above u put space like www dot maxibi dot com or just sample domain.com and the IP address u have writtern there where you can put a little asterik example 2400:8901::f03c:91ff:fe05:**?? I just want to prevent search engine indexing my domain name and IPs where somebody or less people could see what ports are open through this answers. Thanks a lot.